# How to remove 'unchecked' warning from my method?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, pecs

I have following code

```
private static class ParcelableParser<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> parse(List<Parcelable> parcelables) {
        ArrayList<T> parsedData = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(Parcelable parcelable : parcelables) {              
            parsedData.add((T) parcelable);
        }
        return parsedData;
    }
}
```

It is called as follows

```
ParcelableParser<SomeClass> cellParser = new ParcelableParser<SomeClass>();
cellParser.parse(bundle.getParcelableArrayList("some String"));
```

It gives warning `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Parcelable to T`.

No matter what I do, I always have some nasty compilation error.
I have read about PECS rule, but I am not able to apply it here.

sample solution (does not compile)

```
private static class ParcelableParser<T extends Parcelable> {
    private ArrayList<T> parse(List<T> parcelables) {
        ArrayList<T> parsedData = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(T parcelable : parcelables) {               
            parsedData.add((T) parcelable);
        }
        return parsedData;
    }
}
```

Using it as

```
return new ParcelableParser<SomeClass>()
```

.parse(bundle.getParcelableArrayList("SomeString"));

prodces

`The method parse(List<SomeClass>) in the type MyClass.ParcelableParser<SomeClass> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Parcelable>)`

Comment: What are the bounds for `T`?

Comment: As you don't know which type `Parcelable` extends and you rather assume that it extends `T`, you have to make sure that every `Parcelable` extends `T` to erase the warning.

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know parcelable is of type T why don't you use T instead. Try this:

```
public static class ParcelableParser<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> parse(List<T> parcelables) {
        ArrayList<T> parsedData = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(T parcelable : parcelables) {              
            parsedData.add(parcelable);
        }
        return parsedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL, a rather less expensive way of assigning all elements of `parcelables` to `parsedData` is `return parcelables`.

Comment: Yes he could but he might be doing something else within which is hidden from us?

Comment: Yes, he casts type `Parcelable` to `T` to continue using a type safe collection.

Comment: @Smutje of course you are right. Actually, I had some utility method that was just doing type conversion from List<T> to ArrayList<T>. This utility class and method was not needed at all- 
I just get rid of it.